# Compilation Errors while defining vector of tuple in C++11 using GCC v4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, stdtuple

I am trying to define a vector of tuples in C++ 11 as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef std::tuple<uchar, std::string, uchar, float> fruitInfoTuple;
const std::vector<fruitInfoTuple> jointsInfo{
  { 0,  "mango",   100,   -6.01},
  {10,  "apple",   144,    6.25},
  {12,  "orange",  159,    2.59},
  {33,  "banana",  144,  -28.96},
  { 4,  "grapes",  128,    3.79},
};
```

I compile the program with C++11 flag enabled. However, it is showing complication errors as shown below:

```
ravi@lab:~/Desktop/a$ g++  -std=c++11 learn.cpp 
learn.cpp:14:1: error: converting to ‘std::tuple<unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {int, const char (&)[6], int, double}; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Elements = {unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float}]’
 };
 ^
learn.cpp:14:1: error: converting to ‘std::tuple<unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {int, const char (&)[6], int, double}; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Elements = {unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float}]’
learn.cpp:14:1: error: converting to ‘std::tuple<unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {int, const char (&)[7], int, double}; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Elements = {unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float}]’
learn.cpp:14:1: error: converting to ‘std::tuple<unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {int, const char (&)[7], int, double}; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Elements = {unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float}]’
learn.cpp:14:1: error: converting to ‘std::tuple<unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {int, const char (&)[7], int, double}; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Elements = {unsigned char, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char, float}]’
```

I guess GCC 4.8 is not supporting tuple feature. Is there any workaround, please? Please note that I can use `boost` if needed. I just want a clean way of definig the tuple as done above.

Comment: The `int` to `uchar` conversion seems to be the issue.

Comment: Note that C++11 support in GCC 4.8 is incomplete.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but related to your code: Unless you're in a small embedded system there's seldom any need to use the smaller integer types. Go for `int` or`unsigned int`. And if you still want to use smaller integer types for some reason, then use the *standard* small integer types, like e.g. `uint8_t`.

Comment: @Jarod42: It works with newer GCC. However, I am restricted to use GCC 4.8 at this moment. Can you please suggest any alternative way, such as using boost etc?

Comment: @RaviJoshi you can still use `std::make_tuple`

Comment: If you have to use that old version of the gcc there is also a tuple-library in boost which can be used with the gcc since 2.95

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try:

```
const std::vector<fruitInfoTuple> jointsInfo{
    fruitInfoTuple{ 0,  "mango",   100,   -6.01},
    fruitInfoTuple{10,  "apple",   144,    6.25},
    fruitInfoTuple{12,  "orange",  159,    2.59},
    fruitInfoTuple{33,  "banana",  144,  -28.96},
    fruitInfoTuple{ 4,  "grapes",  128,    3.79},
};
```

Comment: It works but is there any way to remove `fruitInfoTuple` in the syntax in every line? I wish a cleaner syntax .....

Comment: `{ uchar(0), std::string("mango"), uchar(100), -6.01f}` should also do the job (no implicit conversions `int` to  `uchar`, `double` to `float`, `const char*` to `std::string`), not sure you prefer it though.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you should use `std::make_tuple` to construct the tuple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef std::tuple<uchar, std::string, uchar, float> fruitInfoTuple;
const std::vector<fruitInfoTuple> jointsInfo{
  std::make_tuple( 0,  "mango",   100,   -6.01),
  std::make_tuple(10,  "apple",   144,    6.25),
  std::make_tuple(12,  "orange",  159,    2.59),
  std::make_tuple(33,  "banana",  144,  -28.96),
  std::make_tuple( 4,  "grapes",  128,    3.79),
};
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < jointsInfo.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::get<1>(jointsInfo[i]) << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Result :

```
mango
apple
orange
banana
grapes
```

Comment: It works but is there any way to remove `std::make_tuple` in the syntax? I wish a cleaner syntax .....

Comment: std::make_tuple is a standard C++11 function. I don't see how it's not a "clean" syntax.
The only other way is to call explicitly the constructor (see @Jarod42 's answer). Upgrading your compiler to support C++14 and C++17 may offer other way to do this.